# Change table cell color by pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I Would like to change the color of the next cell in the table by pressing a button.

For example: If the left button is pressed the color of the next cell in the left will change from white to red and the actual cells color will change from red to white and so on.

In this way we have the illusion that the red square i moving by pressing a button.

Is it possible to do this with Jquery and CSS?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it sure is possible! :)

Comment: if you want to create a moving box effect, you can use html5 canvas, just saying

Comment: Don't expect people to write the whole code for you. At least show us what you have done so far and we'll gladly help you.

Comment: Canvas is over kill for that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nzRxu/ - something I made while bored at work. I added the array but havent used it - something you could implement if you need to keep track of the position in an array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yH2aH/1/ - Not sure what the "rules" are when it gets to the edges, I hate to give you this because you really should try to do these things on your own but if it helps you at all understand jQuery then I guess my 5 minutes won't be completely wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a full example:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="left">Left</button>
<button id="right">Right</button>
<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery:**

```
var position = 0;

$("#left").click(function() {
   position = position -1;
    setCurrentPosition();
});

$("#right").click(function() {
   position = position + 1;    
   setCurrentPosition();
});

$("#up").click(function() {
   position = position -4;
    setCurrentPosition();
});

$("#down").click(function() {
   position = position + 4;    
   setCurrentPosition();
});

function setCurrentPosition() {
    $(".selected").removeClass();
    $("table td").each(function(value) {
        if (value == position) {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
    });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
}

.selected {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzRxu/

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can here is the whole example now how i think this should be done

http://jsfiddle.net/puEbp/2/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="red"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="leftButton">left</button>
<button id="rightButton">right</button>
<button id="downButton">down</button>
<button id="upButton">up</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
$('#rightButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var actualTD = $('td.red');
    if (actualTD.next('td').length > 0) {
        actualTD.next('td').addClass('red');
        actualTD.removeClass('red');
    }        
});
$('#leftButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var actualTD = $('td.red');
    if (actualTD.prev('td').length > 0) {
        actualTD.prev('td').addClass('red');
        actualTD.removeClass('red');
    }        
});    
$('#downButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var actualTD = $('td.red'),
        actualParentTD = actualTD.parent('tr'),
        index = actualTD.index();

    if (actualParentTD.next('tr').length > 0) {
        actualParentTD.next('tr').find('td:eq('+index+')').addClass('red');
        actualTD.removeClass('red');
    }        
});
$('#upButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var actualTD = $('td.red'),
        actualParentTD = actualTD.parent('tr'),
        index = actualTD.index();

    if (actualParentTD.prev('tr').length > 0) {
        actualParentTD.prev('tr').find('td:eq('+index+')').addClass('red');
        actualTD.removeClass('red');
    }        
});
});
```

CSS

```
table td{
border: 2px solid gray;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
.red{
background: red;
}
```

Comment: If you had any trouble, just come back and i will see what i can do for you :D